# display difference between Iphone12 simulator and physic Iphone12

Tags: flutter

I'm devlopping an app with Flutter.
Evrything work properly when I test it on the Iphone12 simulator.
But when I tried to test it on my real phone,
I got some bugs.
The size of some elements were bigger in my real phone, and I got some display issues..
Any clue about that ?

I'm currently downloading the latest upgrade of IOS on my phone

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.